# Flask application is not exposing to external world in docker

Tags: docker, flask, amazon-ec2

I'm hosting a flask application in docker container through AWS EC2, which will display the contents of the file that is uploaded to it.

I'm facing an strange issue is that my application is not exposing to the external world, but it works on localhost. When I try to hit on my public ip of the machine, it is showing "refused to connect" (Note: Security groups are fine)

docker ps command showing my container is running fine on the expected port number. Can you please let me know how can i resolve it to make it work? Thanks in advance

Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350

Here is my Dockerfile,

```
  FROM ubuntu:latest
  RUN mkdir /testing
  WORKDIR /testing
  ADD . /testing
  RUN apt-get update&&apt-get install -y pip
  RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
  CMD flask run
```

In my requirements.txt file, I'm having flask to be installed in docker.

Here is my flask code and html file,

```
    from flask import Flask,render_template,request
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route("/")
    def file():
        return render_template("index.html")
    @app.route("/upload", methods= ['POST','GET'])
    def test():
             print("test")
             if request.method == 'POST':
                   print("test3")
                   file = request.files['File'].read()
                   return file

   if __name__ == "__main__":
             app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

index.html:

```
    <html>
       <body>
         <form action = "http://<publiciIPofmachine>:5000/upload" method = "POST" enctype = 
        "multipart/form-data">
        <input type = "file" name = "File" />
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

docker logs:

Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)

- Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: on
- Running on all addresses.
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
- Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Here are my docker commands that is used,

```
    docker build -t <name> .
    docker run -d -t -p 5000:80 <imagename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the docker run command:

#### Background

That is what [docs say](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/):

```
-p=[]      : Publish a container's port or a range of ports to the host
               format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort
               Both hostPort and containerPort can be specified as a
               range of ports. When specifying ranges for both, the
               number of container ports in the range must match the
               number of host ports in the range, for example:
                   -p 1234-1236:1234-1236/tcp
```

So you are publishing port in format: hostPort:containerPort

#### Solution

Instead of your code:

```
    docker run -d -t -p 5000:80 <imagename>
```

You should do

```
     docker run -d -t -p 80:5000 <imagename>
```

But it's good practice to define the EXPOSE layer in your container :)

The EXPOSE has two roles:

- Its kind of documentation, whoever is reading your Dockerfile, they know what port should be exposed.
- You can use the `--publish-all | -P` flag to publish all exposed ports.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the response. It did work. My frontend is working fine. But now my backend is not receiving the request. Even there is no logs captured in docker for POST method. But my flask app is working  fine without docker. Can you please light up here?

Comment: Could us show please, how you are starting the frontend and the backend? If both are in the docker, you should use the `--link` option, or put them in the same network, which is preffered.